# Permanently attract chickens Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing Minecraft Bedrock on my Xbox One (v1.14.1) and I am trying to develop my chicken farm. My goal is to have the chickens attracted to a section of the chicken coop without me needing to physically stand there holding seeds, as the point of this is to easily enter and exit the coop without immediately filling my inventory with eggs (I have way too many chickens, like easily 200+).

I know that chickens follow wheat seeds, but I am trying to find a way to get them to follow the seeds without me needing to intervene. So far I have tried framing the seeds, which didn't work at all, and building a glass chamber with a dropped seed in it, which worked however the dropped seeds obviously eventually despawn after a while which isn't ideal.

Any way I can do this?

Comment: Please actually read the descriptions of the tags you use. [tag:minecraft] is currently used for Minecraft Java edition (but there's a discussion ongoing that could change that, see sidebar on the desktop website) and [tag:chickens] is about a game called "Chickens!".

Comment: the only thing i could think of is using a dropper to periodically drop seeds to the ground using a large enough redstone clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop of redstone repeaters to periodically unlock a hopper beneath the seeds, then pass the seed back into a dropper, lock the hopper, and dispense the seed. This will renew the seeds' age so it never despawns.

Comment: this sounds excellent, thank you! I will implement this when I get home to double check and then mark as answered